# Change case using Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How to change case of some backreference in `String.replace()`? I want to match some part in text and change its case to upper/lower.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a regex for your match then pass a function, here's an example for converting CSS properties:

```
"margin-top".replace(/-([a-z])/, function(a, l) { return l.toUpperCase(); })
//result = "marginTop"
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/CNA9T/).  This regex takes any `-alpha` (one character) and turns it into `-upperalpha`, it's just an example though, any regex works, and you'll want to call [`.toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) or [`.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) (or anything else really) on the *second* argument in the callback, which is the current match.

Answer (score -3):

Just use a case-insensitive regex switch on the pattern that you wish to replace.

Something like:

```
myString.replace(/AnyCasE/gi, "anycase")
```

Comment: I don't know exact string to match. Sorry, maybe my question is not clear.