# Restrict action of toLowerCase to part of a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to convert most of a string to lower case, except for those characters inside of brackets. After converting everything outside the brackets to lower case, I then want to remove the brackets. So giving `{H}ell{o} World` as input should give `Hello world` as output. Removing the brackets is simple, but is there a way to selectively make everything outside the brackets lower case with regular expressions? If there's no simple regex solution, what's the easiest way to do this in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var str='{H}ell{o} World';

str = str.replace(/{([^}]*)}|[^{]+/g, function (m,p1) {
    return (p1)? p1 : m.toLowerCase();} );

console.log(str);
```

The pattern match:

```
{([^}]*)}  # all that is between curly brackets
           # and put the content in the capture group 1

|          # OR

[^{]+      # anything until the regex engine meet a {
           # since the character class is all characters but {
```

the callback function has two arguments:

`m` the complete match

`p1` the first capturing group

it returns `p1` if `p1` is not empty
else the whole match `m` in lowercase.

Details:

```
"{H}"    p1 contains H (first part of the alternation)
         p1 is return as it. Note that since the curly brackets are
         not captured, they are not in the result. -->"H"

"ell"    (second part of the alternation) p1 is empty, the full match 
         is returned in lowercase -->"ell"

"{o}"    (first part) -->"o"

" World" (second part) -->" world"
```

Comment: Works great! Can you walk me through the regex pattern?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is probably what you are looking for:
[Change case using Javascript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890328/change-case-using-javascript-regex)

Detect on the first curly brace instead of a hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all parentheses are well balanced, the parts that should be lower cased are contained like this:

1. Left hand side is either the start of your string or `}`
2. Right hand side is either the end of your string or `{`

This the code that would work:

```
var str = '{H}ELLO {W}ORLD';

str.replace(/(?:^|})(.*?)(?:$|{)/g, function($0, $1) {
    return $1.toLowerCase();
});
// "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would amend @Jack s solution as follows :

```
var str = '{H}ELLO {W}ORLD';

str = str.replace (/(?:^|\})(.*?)(?:\{|$)/g, function($0, $1) {
  return $1.toLowerCase ();
});
```

Which performs both the lower casing and the bracket removal in one operation!